# Можно ли получать посты со стены с фильтрацией по дате?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Есть ли возможность получать все посты в vk api, определенного человека, сделанные не позже указанной даты? Почитал документацию, там, `wall.search` позволяет искать записи по содержимому.

Comment: Вы хотите со всех существующих стен найти или с какой-то конкретной? Если с конкретной, то почему не воспользоваться методом `wall.get` и не фильтровать по идентификатору пользователя и по дате (они возвращаются в ответе)

Comment: @Алексей, с конкретной стены. Проблема состоит в том, что wall.get возвращает максимум 100 записей, а у меня там может быть десятки тысяч записей, размещенных не позже моей даты. Мне, в принципе, подошло бы, получить число записей, которые удовлетворяют 3 фильтрам: автор, содержимое и дата на определенной стене.

Comment: Но ведь ничто не мешает сделать десяток другой запросов со смещением `offset` и потом результат отфильтровать

Comment: @Алексей, а это будет не слишком большая нагрузка для фильтрации, например,  50000 постов?

Comment: Ну вам все равно не все 50000 надо лопатить а лишь до определенного момента, пока дата не станет выше указанной. Но, собственно, выбора то и нет) Задаете интервал, с какой частотой обращаться к апи в секунду и ждете)  Причем все равно придется наверное это делать в методе `execute` там как хак, можно несколько запросов сделать внутри и цикл... то есть мало того что вы крутите в цикле execute, да еще внутри него цикл с offset можно провернуть

Comment: @Алексей, нет, мне нужно будет именно 50000 перелопатить. Минут за 20 просчитается? А зачем делать execute? Я вообще на php собирался писать...

Comment: execute - как я сказал можно запросы в запросе писать и цикл внутри организовать - что даст некую бОльшую выборку, например получить в итоге из запроса 500 записей, нежели просто к методу обращаться по 100 записей....А также там внутри можно отфильтровывать данные. .......через php или через что еще - не важно. к методу можно обратиться откуда угодно

Comment: @Алексей, execute на своем VkScript... То есть выборку можно организовать прямо в нем, а в PHP просто получить результат? Внутри него запускать бесконечный цикл, в котором с шагом 100 менять offset, проверять по 100 записей на автора и содержимое, при совпадении увеличивать счетчик и в случае выхода за дату прерывать цикл, так?

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно. Как предлагали в комментариях, нужно использовать offset. При использовании токена сообщества можно добиться скорости в 20 запросов в секунду. По несложной математике получаем 2000 записей в секунду.

Также в комментариях предлагали использовать execute запрос с VKScript для решения этой задачи. С его помощью можно, теоретически, получать 2500 записей за один запрос.

Решение на VKScript:

```js
// Параметры процедуры
var owner_id = -1;
var offset = 0;

var response = [];
var i = 0;
while (i < 25) {
    response = response + API.wall.get({"owner_id": owner_id, "offset": offset}).items;
    offset = offset + 100;
    i = i + 1;
}
return response;
```

Эта процедура вернёт 2500 записей, а фильтровать лучше уже на своей стороне, в vkscript будет не удобно и можно попасть в лимиты. За секунду, теоретически, с токеном сообщества, можно будет получить 500'000 записей.